# proof the derivate of gamma function using the limit definition

Tags: proof-writing, special-functions, gamma-function

> using $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(z)=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n!n^z}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+n)}$ proof that
>   $$\psi(z+1)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}-\ln n\right)+\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{z}{l(z+l)}$$

my attempt:

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(z+1)&=z\Gamma(z)\\
\ln\Gamma(z+1)&=\ln z\Gamma(z)\\
&=\ln z+\ln\Gamma(z)\\
&=\ln z+\ln\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n!n^z}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+n)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\ln z+\ln\frac{n!n^z}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+n)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\ln(n!n^z)-\sum_{l=1}^{n}\ln(z+l)
\end{align}$$
but i dont know how to finish, did im done alright? there any hint?

Comment: Proof it from the other side:

$$\psi(z+1)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}-\ln(n)\right)+\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{z}{l(z+l)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\psi(z+1)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}-\ln (n)\right)+\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{l=1}^{x}\frac{z}{l(z+l)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\psi(z+1)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\text{H}_n-\ln (n)\right)+\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\text{H}_x+\text{H}_z-\text{H}_{x+z}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\psi(z+1)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\text{H}_n-\ln (n)\right)+\text{H}_z\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\text{H}_z$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the limit definition of the Gamma function, we have

$$\Gamma(z)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!n^z}{\prod_{k=0}^n (z+k)}$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log \Gamma (z+1)&=\log z+\log \Gamma(z)\\\\
&=\log z+\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log(n!n^z)-\sum_{k=0}^n \log(z+k)\right)
\end{align}$$

Now, the Digamma function can be written

$$\begin{align}
\psi(z+1)&=\frac1z+\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log(n)-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{(z+k)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{(z+k)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac1k-\frac z{k(z+k)}\right)\right)\\\\
&=-\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k -\log(n)\right)+\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{z}{\ell(z+\ell)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you, It is simpler than I imagined.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  You were on the right track.